# Prove $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=3(abc+bcd+cda+dab)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers and $a+b+c+d=0$. prove:
>
> $$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=3(abc+bcd+cda+dab)$$

Using Euler's identity: if $x+y+z=0$ then $x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$.  in this problem substitute $x=a+b,y=c,z=d:$

$$(a+b)^3+c^3+d^3=3cd(a+b)$$
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=3(a+b)(cd-ab)=3(acd-a^2b+bcd-ab^2)$$
Although I am sure my approach is right, but I should have $3(abc+bcd+cda+dab)$ at the RHS. I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3(acd-a^2b+bcd-ab^2) = 3(cd(a + b) - ab(a+b)) = 3(cd(a + b) + ab(c+d))  = 3(abc + abd + acd + bcd)$$

Comment: That should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes. very good trick! I think it was easier if you used an step earlier $3(a+b)(cd-ab)$.

Comment: @Soheil You are correct. I just continued it from the point you left it.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)=a^3+b^3-3ab(c+d)$$

Comment: If I substitute it at the equation I can't factor out $(a+b)$ on the RHS

Comment: Start with your $(a+b)^3+c^3+d^3=3(a+b)cd$.  Replace $(a+b)^3$ with my formula.  Now you have four cubes minus $3ab(c+d)$ on the left.  Move $3ab(c+d)$ to the right, which now has all four $3abc+3abd+3acd+3bcd$

Comment: I got it, Nice answer. $+1$